# What else do we need to do to go public?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

With 8 days and almost 200 questions, with 6 users over 1000 rep and a few more that are close, what more do we need to do to go public?

I noticed that we are starting to drop off in questions asked. We only have 7 open questions in the last 24 hours; voting appears to be dropping off too.

I want to keep the momentum strong as we move into public. Let's do it.

### Is there anything else we need to do as a community to make it happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Between now and next week, the [Community Manager team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) will be evaluating the progress of Mythology in the private beta. With [189 questions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) at the time of writing, we have plenty of content to consider.

Early in the week, we should come back to you with one of three possible outcomes:

1. [Failed in private beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/) (honestly, unlikely at this point),
2. Passed to public beta, or
3. Suggestions for course correction.

If you have questions that you think typify a high-quality Q&A site about Mythology, please continue asking.

Comment: Okay, thanks! If there's milestones we should be hitting or goals we should be accomplishing between now and then, please let us know! :)

Comment: Will they announce the pro tems at that time too?

Comment: @fredsbend: That can take a few more days/weeks.

Answer (score 6):

Waiting to go public will only cause harm to the site. We have everything we need to be successful: a core group of dedicated community members, a great collection of high-quality questions and answers, and several ground rules regarding sources, acceptable questions, and other topics. What we need now is to start getting more activity, and the only way we can begin to do this is if we go public.

It's true that we still have to work out some issues with our scope, but I don't think those issues can be resolved in private beta: we need a bigger base of content in order to determine what makes a bad question, and we will only get that if we go public.

It's also true that only 85% of our questions currently have answers, but I think that's a good thing. Answers on this site are high-quality and well-sourced. Writing a good answer takes time, especially when the question requires specialised knowledge (which is the case for most questions on this site). The questions that remain unanswered aren't unanswered because they are bad, but are unanswered because we just haven't gotten to them yet.