# Are we becoming too Greek?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is the resurrection of an earlier ([now deleted](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183/what-else-do-we-need-to-do-to-go-public/185#185)) answer of mine, which, as per the recommendation of durron597, has become a new question.

I took a look the other day at our tags. Here are our most popular ones:

- [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) - 67 questions
- [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse) - 22 questions
- [mythical-creatures](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) - 16 questions
- [sumerian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumerian) - 12 questions
- [gods](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) - 11 questions
- [egyptian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egyptian) - 10 questions
- [mesopotamia](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesopotamia) - 10 questions
- [everything-else](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everything-else) - <10 questions per tag.

<sup><sup>As of May 9, 2015 22:28 UTC</sup></sup>

We will (hopefully) enter public beta soon. New users often follow the pattern of questions on a given beta site. Monkey see, monkey do. If new users follow this trend, almost exactly <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> (currently 67 our of 200) of all our new questions will be [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek).

Is this potentially a problem?

I should add that I've seen similar things happen on other beta sites, and the scope can get somewhat narrowed, though I can't prove that it dates back to activity in the site's private beta.

Comment: I've asked myself this a few times before, and it's why I've deliberately not asked any more greek questions even though I'm far more familiar with that mythos than any other.

Answer (score 11):

## I don't think this is a problem.

Greek mythology is very popular; it's fairly well documented and the stories are good.

If you look at the [tags on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), Java, Javascript, and C# are at the top. Java has twice as many posts as Python, the #7 tag.

I have never seen anything to suggest that having a wide range of tag popularity is a problem, as long as we do our best as a community to make sure the questions in the other tags get answered, too.

We should revisit this when we go public, just in case, but I don't think the other mythologies will die then, either. And, of course, this is self correcting; those of us who think this is a problem will take the time to ask more questions in the less popular mythologies (which is already happening!). I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As another example, SFF.SE is heavily dominated by Harry Potter, Star Wars and Star Trek. Whethere that's a detriment to the site is debatable, but IMHO it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem: mythology is a huge topic, and if we focus on one tiny portion of the subject we will not realise our full potential.

However, this has an easy fix: make an effort to ask more non-greek questions. The more non-greek questions there are, the more likely someone will want to learn more and read a non-greek myth and thus ask more non-greek questions.

Answer (score 4):

When most people think of mythology, Greek myths are the first thing that comes to mind (Norse second), so I think that distribution is natural.

I hate to ask questions in my speciality area- I either know a good answer or it's something pretty obscure (like hedgehog goddesses). Beyond that, most of my real questions are going to be about Greek things.

Comment: Hedgehog Goddesses? Intriguing...

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask even if it's obscure. Some of us might enjoy the challenge!

Comment: Abaset, for instance. 

https://henadology.wordpress.com/theology/abaset/